# Quartz.Net - Execute A Job Now And Remove Trigger and Job in ADODataStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I would like to be able to create a job dynamically with a trigger that tells the job to execute now, and provide a loading dialog in the asp.net application while the job executes.  Once the job is finished, I want to remove the associated job, and trigger from the QRTZ_DB.  I am providing two ways of executing jobs: 1) Run Now (the problem i have stated) 2) Schdeule job..which I plan to implement once I get this working.

Also, if someone could comment on how to not allow a job to be executed until all instances of that type are completed executed.  I have had some problems with jobs not having enough time to execute before the next one gets launched.

Thanks

Comment: SimpleTrigger("", DataTime.UTCNow) //executes job at specified time and does not repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to limit concurrent execution of a given job type is to have that job implement IStatefulJob instead of IJob.

Answer (score 6):

The IStatefulJob is deprecated, decorate your calss with the DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another way besides IStatefulJob

Depend on your description,you can use lock and an object,like

```
static Object obj=new Object();//class field

.........
lock(obj)
{
    your logic goes here.
}
```

Or Some like this,

```
//class field
static Object obj=new Object();
bool executing=false;
.....

if(executing)
    return;
lock(obj)
{
    executing=true;
    your logic goes here.
}
executing=false;
```

Comment: i  dont think this will work, since quartz instantiates a new instance of your class everytime.

Comment: Thank you ,Taylor.I got your idea.We can use a static object to sync the logic.